# Elasticsearch display number value as string

Tags: elasticsearch

I found bellow data in elasticsearch that confused me :

```
 {
    "_index": "statsd-2015.09.24",
    "_type": "counter",
    "_id": "AU__eqbL4jN5fst_IEyK",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "ns": "statsd",
       "grp": "bad_lines_seen",
       "tgt": "",
       "act": "",
       "val": 0,
       "@timestamp": 1443072093000
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "statsd-2015.09.24",
    "_type": "counter",
    "_id": "AU__fKQM4jN5fst_IEy_",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "ns": "statsd",
       "grp": "bad_lines_seen",
       "tgt": "",
       "act": "",
       "val": "0",
       "@timestamp": "1443072852000"
    }
 }
```

Why the field **val** and **timestamp** are displayed in different formats?

- In first document , they are numbers
- In second document, they are strings

They are in the same index and type whose mapping is :

```
{
   "statsd-2015.09.24": {
      "mappings": {
         "counter": {
            "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "act": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "grp": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "ns": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "tgt": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "val": {
                  "type": "long"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found differences between field types in the **source** of the documents. The `_source` is the original JSON submitted to ElasticSearch to index a document.

However, it isn't what is actually indexed : this is just stored for other purposes (more information can be found in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html)).

In your case, the `val` is mapped as a `long` field, so the string value provided in the second document is in fact parsed to its long value.

You can check this easily : try to index a document like this

```
{
  "ns": "statsd",
  "grp": "bad_lines_seen",
  "tgt": "",
  "act": "",
  "val": "abc",
  "@timestamp": "1443072852000"
}
```

You'll have the following parsing error :

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [val]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"abc\"];
```

So, to answer your question : your values' types are different, but in fact the values are both indexed as `long` due to parsing.

Answer (score 0):

For additional information:

output :  `{"@timestamp": "2019-03-21T10:52:35.435Z"}`

Index mapping: `"@timestamp": {"type": "date"}`

---

output : `{"@timestamp": 1443072852000}`

Index Mapping: `"@timestamp": {"type": "date","format": "epoch_millis"}`